# Run on several cores

Tags: c++, visual-studio, multicore

Initially, I have a program, which I divided into several parts so that each part is executed by a specific core. So, in my C++ project I have several "main files". I would like to know if it is possible from Visual Studio 2017 to say "Such core executes such.cpp".

Using the simple example of a counter and a display: The counter turns on core 1 and sends its data to the display on core 2. Is this possible to run on Visual Studio 2017?

Comment: You don't get to decide which core to use. OS does.

Comment: i think you need much more help then what you can get on SO. you should document yourself a bit more about parallel execution

Comment: You don't have 4 separate `int main() { ... }` do you?

Comment: @Ron: Not in portable C++, but since it's essential to High-Performance Computing every modern OS does support that. It's called _Thread Affinity_. Having said that, it's understood that programming for such environments requires above-average skill, and the question suggests otherwise.

Comment: @MSalters I was under the impression the Thread Affinity does not guarantee the actual code will be executed on a particular core. And is to be avoided.

Comment: @Ron: Best practice is to set a thread affinity **mask** which allows a thread to run on a subset of cores, where the subset contains more than one core. E.g. it's very reasonable to set a mask that covers all cores on a single CPU. But affinity masks are absolute binding on the OS, ignoring them might invalidate program correctness (e.g. because two threads aren't synchronized correctly when run concurrently on two cores, where their affinity mask would prevent it)

Comment: @MSalters I've heard stories about people who write code that assumes strict affinity masks and their pain and suffering when things happen such as hot-unplug of the CPU. Proper synchronization is really the better idea.

Comment: @ZanLynx: Well, if you restrict your threads to cores 4-7, and you then remove all those cores by unplugging the CPU, then yes your program will stop. So in that sense you can't guarantee that your code will be executed, the chosen CPU may not even have power.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible, and in fact it would be pointless.

In your simple idea, core2 has nothing to do until core1 sends it some data, at which point core1 would be waiting for core2. So at most one of the two cores is active at any time. It would be far more efficient to use one core for that.

To use multiple cores in C++, you need `<thread>`. Using `<thread>` is anything but automatic. However, once you have threads, using multiple cores *is* automatic.

Answer (score 0):

There is a call in Windows that can limit your process to specific core:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setprocessaffinitymask

In this case you have to launch multiple proceses, set their affinities and do different task in each one.

And there is also one for threads:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setthreadaffinitymask

In a simple case you would launch new thread for each of your task, set their affinities, run tasks in threads and then wait for threads to join with your main thread.